# What channels can/does Push Notifications get transmitted over when in a roaming situation?

Tags: ios

I can't find full details in the Apple Push Notification guide regarding this -

How is an Apple Push Notification actually sent? i.e over what channels and how in various circumstances?

If a user goes abroad they will no longer be using the cellular data network belonging to their wireless carrier and the phone will be in data roaming mode. Does this mean if the user will have to pay more for the data that is sent as part of a push notification?

What if the user turns off data roaming? In this case can a push notification still be received? (Would it come over Wifi, what if wifi is also disabled?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in the same way as any other internet connection. If the device is not connected to the internet, they won't be received. If there is wifi connection, they will be received without problems (the case of iPad without 3G).

Note that even if there is internet connection, push notifications are not guaranteed to be received and the user can switch them off completely in Notification Center.

The actual connection is initiated by device to port 5223 (polling). If this port is blocked on your network (e.g. by firewall), no notifications are received.

Comment: Thanks. Push notifications don't always come via Wifi, they may come over the telephony channel. I was trying to see if data roaming is turned off and wifi isn't available if they could come by another mechanism (i.e. theoretically it ought to be possible for Apple to implement them as an SMS in this situation? And on the device intercept the SMS and make it appear as a notification.)

Comment: This is too complicated :) You can't do something like this on iOS. And always remember that even when internet connection works fine, the delivery is not guaranteed. The notification can be lost on the way and never delivered. When your application is started, it always has to check the server for news.

Comment: *I* wasn't thinking of doing this, I was just wondering if Apple themselves were doing it to cover this particular situation. Cheers.

Comment: If a push notification was sent via a cellular channel (if they don't have wifi connectivity) and the user didn't have a data plan for their phone, or they did have a data plan but it was at or over the data limit, then wouldn't that cost them too indirectly? (as the PN contains a payload and thus would contribute, even if a small amount towards the amount of data downloaded over the cellular channel).

Comment: It would be paid by the user, not by Apple. But SMS are paid by the sender.